# ValueError: unknown url type with DeepLab demo.ipynb

Tags: google-colaboratory

I am running Demo DeepLab.ipnyb using Google Colab. Demo provides images work well. When I tried to add my own image, I receive an error "ValueError: unknown url type: '/content/harshu-06032019.png'. I see that the file is uploaded to Colab.

Any help on why I am getting this error is appreciated.

I tried to put this file into Google Drive and grant access to Colab by mounting the Google Drive. That doesn't work as well.

But if the file is uploaded to google drive, I am getting the error "Cannot retrieve image. Please check url"

This is the code provided by DeepLabv3+

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-ba1edc5ae51a> in <module>()
     24 
     25 image_url = IMAGE_URL or _SAMPLE_URL % SAMPLE_IMAGE
---> 26 run_visualization(image_url)

5 frames
/usr/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py in _parse(self)
    382         self.type, rest = splittype(self._full_url)
    383         if self.type is None:
--> 384             raise ValueError("unknown url type: %r" % self.full_url)
    385         self.host, self.selector = splithost(rest)
    386         if self.host:

ValueError: unknown url type: '/content/harshu-06032019.png'
```

Answer (score 0):

To fix this "ValueError: unknown url type: '/content/harshu-06032019.png'", follow these steps:

1. Remove `content` from the URL path
2. The path to your image should only be `harshu-06032019.png`
3. run `!ls` to see if the image file is present